# Computed field is getting updated in solr index only when we do full rebuild of reindex

Tags: solr, indexing, computed-field

I have a Sitecore instance running on Sitecore v9 update 2 using
SOLR. So I have created 3 new computed fields, these fields are
working properly when I rebuild index or re-index tree (both master
and web) but when I publish any Sitecore item the computed fields
are not getting updated, in fact computed field is missing from the
solr `sitecore_web_index` when I do publish.

`IndexUpdateStrategy` used: `OnpublishEndAsync`*

Is there any other configuration that I should look for when it comes to reindex on publishing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the code of your computed field?

Comment: And what is code of the base class you're using?

Comment: Apologies ,I have repeated the question twice. Yes other computed fields are getting indexed properly, on item publish

Comment: So it's the problem with this particular computed index field. In the code you added to your question, you only join a list of strings. And what is the code of the base class which is used to get that list of strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen a similar problem in the past with new computed fields disappearing from indexes on publish. It was caused by multiple Sitecore instances with different code version connected to the same database and Solr server.

One of the differences between the full index rebuild (or re-index tree) and on-publish indexing is the fact that the full index rebuild runs only on the Sitecore instance where it was triggered. However, event-based indexing will be performed by every instance that is connected to the same Event Queue table and has indexing enabled.

If you have more than one Sitecore instance connected to the same database and Solr server and all of them use `onPublishEndAsync` indexing strategy, then each of them will try to index the published item based on the configs and DLLs they have. In case your new computed fields are not deployed to other instances yet, then it is likely they will remove new fields from the index when they receive the `publish:end:remote` event.

Please note that it is recommended that only one instance performs indexing operations in a Sitecore environment, unless you have multiple Solr servers in a geo-distributed set up.